# How to resolve "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType" error, while working on translating with googletrans?

Tags: python, json, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

How can I resolve TypeError while translating with googletrans?
TypeError occurs on 'result = translator.translate(messages[i], dest='en')', and I can't understand because type of result is 'googletrans.models.Translated'.

I used a colab. Also I made a folder named 'translation' and text files(0.txt, 1.txt...) in 'content' folder.

This is my code:

```
!pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1
import os

from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=[
      'translate.google.com',
      'translate.google.co.kr',
])

messages = []
DATA_PATH = '/content/'

for i in range(100):
  file = open(f'{DATA_PATH}{i}.txt', "r")

  msg = [l.strip('\\n') for l in file.readlines()]
  messages.append(' '.join(msg))

for i in range(100):
  result = translator.translate(messages[i], dest='en')

  file_path = os.path.join("translation", f"{i}.txt")
  with open(file_path, "w") as file:
        file.write(result.text)
```

Comment: Has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is one of the text files in your directory is empty. Because of this the `messages` variable is an empty string and you receive the error from the translator class.

A way you can solve this is to find the empty strings and add a message to it. For example one method you can use is:

```
messages = []


for i in range(100):
  file = open(f'{DATA_PATH}{i}.txt', "r")
  msg = [l.strip('\\n') for l in file.readlines()]
  messages.append(' '.join(msg))

for idx,message in enumerate(messages):
  if message == '':
    messages[idx] = 'Empty'
```